# Connecting my android device to eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, adb, sony-xperia

I can't get Eclipse to detect my Xperia E. I switched on the USB Debugging, tried adb kill-server and start server, tried both the MTP & MSC mode,modified the android_usb.inf file. I just can't get the device manager to update my driver. It shows there is no Android ADB Interface driver in my list of Device drivers. Please help me out. Trying to test my apps on my device since the last two days !

Comment: restart device try to connect or uninstall and install pc suite on your pc!

Comment: I have the PC Companion installed on my laptop.

Comment: make sure you installed this http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html

Comment: install PdaNet on your laptop

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok, This did it for me. Connected Xperia E to my laptop. Enabled USB Debugging. Went to the Computer > Right Click > Manage > Device Manager > Other Devices > Android ADB Interface > Right Click > Update Driver > Browse my computer for Driver Software > Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer .Now, here is the **MAIN** part. Instead of looking for Android ADB Interface, scroll down & you will find a driver named **Sony so0101** . Click next & install it. Now, Eclipse detects my device !!

**NOTE : USB DEBUGGING must be enabled ,otherwise the device (XPERIA E) will show under portable devices and no Android ADB Interface will be present to update.**

Hope, it helps someone as it took me two days to figure it out ! Cheers !

Comment: +1 and thanks, it solved my problem also. But I clicked on all devices after clicking on Let me pick from a list option--> then Sony --> then so0101

Answer (score 1):

Go in platform-tools and type `adb kill-server` then `adb start-server`.

platform-tools is in your sdk in my case is `E:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\platform-tools`

Answer (score 0):

I have nexus 4 and faced the same issue. When you go to My Computer > Manage > Device Manager > Other Devices , it was showing me Nexus 4 there and not "Android ADB Interface". To fix this, right click on nexus 4 and click on update. from two option select "Browse my computer for driver software" and then select "Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer ". you will see "Android ADB Interface" as an option. Select and install it. Now AVD manager will show the device.