# Eclipse doesn't detect my Android device

Tags: android, eclipse, usb, detection

I use an Iconia Tab from Acer to debug an application. I've already used it a few months ago and it worked very well. But as I try to update the project, Eclipse can't find the device connected.

Yes, the usb debugging is already activated. I updated the specific drivers and the tablet is detected by the computer (as I was asked if I want to open it, like it did before). I try to use the adb commands kill-server and start-server, even reboot with adb usb but the result of "adb devices" still is a blank list.

**EDIT:** Thanks for the answerer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17483877/connecting-my-android-device-to-eclipse?rq=1), I checked for the periphericals devices (as I did before), but right-click on the "multimedia player" (it was detected as this) and "solve the problemes" by installing again the android interface. Why had it been uninstalled, I don't have a clue, but now, "adb devices" shows it!

Comment: Have you tried download the drivers for your devices. Also try different usb ports maybe?

Comment: What environment? Linux/Windows? Drivers installed?

Comment: What operating system are you working in? I have setup USB debugging on Mac, Linux and Windows. Windows and Mac for me normally works out of the box. With linux i would usually have to add a udev rule with the vender ID of the device. With out doing this i get the same problem of it just not showing up.

Comment: My environment is Windows 7 Pro.

Answer (score 3):

I have nexus 4 and faced the same issue. When you go to My Computer > Manage > Device Manager > Other Devices , it was showing me Nexus 4 there and not "Android ADB Interface". To fix this, right click on nexus 4 and click on update. from two option select "Browse my computer for driver software" and then select "Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer ". you will see "Android ADB Interface" as an option. Select and install it. Now AVD manager will show the device.

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue with my Galaxy S3 (GT-I9300). I solved this issue after "Factory Data Reset". Now when i connect my phone with USB ,Eclipse shows my device perfectly.

Hopes it's helpful!...

Comment: In fact, it's for a school project so they lend me the tablet. I don't know if I can reset it... :x

Comment: From the Apps menu, locate the Settings app.Settings -> Backup & reset/Privacy->"Factory Data Reset". It works fine.Don't Worry about it.